# read a txt file and put the values in a list (c++)

Tags: c++, list, file, linked-list

The Values in the txt file are in this format:

```
4  
2 3  
5 6  
3 7  
6 9
```

and the output have to look like this:

```
[2:3][5:6][3:7][6:9]
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <stdio.h>  
using namespace std;  

class node {
    public:  
        int info;
        node* next;
        node(){
            next = NULL;
        }
        node (int value){
            info = value;
            next = NULL;
        }
};

class list {
    private:
        node* head;
    public: 
        list() {            //Constructor
            head = NULL;
        }

    void insert(int value){
        if (head == NULL){
            head = new node;
            head -> info = value;
            return;
        }
        node *temp = head;
        while (temp) {
            temp = temp -> next;
        }
        temp -> next = new node;
        temp -> info = value;
    }

    void showlist(){
        node* temp = head;
        temp = temp -> next;        //ignore first number in txt file
        cout << "Liste \n" << endl;
        while (temp){
            printf ("%d", temp -> info);
            //cout << temp -> info << endl;
            temp = temp -> next;
        }
    }   

    ~list() {           //Destructor
        node* temp = head;
        while (head -> next != NULL) {
            delete temp -> next;
            temp -> next = NULL;
            temp = temp -> next;
        }
        delete head -> next;
        head -> next = NULL;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    list stone;

    FILE* fp;

    if (argc > 1)
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    else 
        fp = fopen("output.txt", "r");

    if (!fp)
        printf("Can't open file \n");
    else {
        int value, state;
        int i = 0;
        do {
            state = fscanf(fp, "%d", &value);
            if (state != EOF){
                stone.insert(value);
            }
        stone.showlist();
        }
        while (state != EOF);
        fclose (fp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There are no errors but i got a crash report if I want to execute it.
I ignored the requested format as a start.

Comment: Run it in a debugger and see where it crashes.

Comment: Include file error <iostream> ????? can use filestream right c++!

Comment: Okay a debugger said it's a runtime error. (and I wrote #include <iostream>. didn't forget the <> )

Comment: Why not just use `std::list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block in `insert` looks incorrect:

```
    while (temp) {
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    temp -> next = new node;
```

After the `while` loop, `temp` is `NULL`, so you can't call `temp -> next`.

Comment: Oh thanks! That was the mistake. But now I got a weird number at the end of my correct output list.

Comment: Hopefully you're on track now; @liuml07 made some more good points to look at

Answer (score 1):

There are several bugs in your code. I'll list several obvious ones for you consideration:

1. What do you deal with the *head*? You ignore the head while showing the list but it actually holds the first value.
2. Every time you try to use the `node->next`, you should guarantee that the node is not NULL
3. As the first answer points out, the temp is NULL after `while` loop. The solution *may* be `while (temp->next)`
4. The destructor of the list is incorrect that you will encounter segmentation fault for empty list
5. You use `printf` and `fgets` instead of `iostream`, and you use two classes. Which one do you prefer, C or C++? Choose one you like.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a formatted answer . And yet you make no arrangements to print it as

[2:3][5:6][3:7][6:9]

```
//THE MODIFICATIONS I MADE ARE MINUTE. BUT THEY'LL GIVE YOU THE RESULT YOU DESIRE.
// MODIFY TEXT FILE FOR ANY MORE INPUTS IF YOU NEED TO INSERT MORE
 #include <iostream>  
 #include <stdio.h>  
 #include<conio.h>
 using namespace std;  

class node {
public:  
    int info;
    node* next;
    node(){
        next = NULL;
    }
    node (int value){
        info = value;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

class list {
private:
    node* head;
public: 
    list() {            //Constructor
        head = NULL;
    }

void insert(int value){
    if (head == NULL){
        head = new node;
        head -> info = value;
        return;
    }
    node *temp = head;
    while (temp->next) { //MODIFIED INSERT LOOP TERMINATION CONDN
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    temp -> next = new node;
    temp -> info = value;
}

void showlist(){
    node* temp = head;
  //  temp = temp -> next;  //ignore first number in txt file _ UNNECESSARY - COMMENTED
    cout << "List \n" << endl;
    while (temp){
        if(!temp->next){break;} //, temp -> info,(temp -> next)-> info);
        else {printf ("[%d:%d]\n", temp -> info,(temp -> next)-> info);}
        //cout << temp -> info << endl;
        temp = (temp -> next)->next;
    }
}   

~list() {           //Destructor
    node* temp = head;
    while (head -> next != NULL) {
        delete temp -> next;
        temp -> next = NULL;
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    delete head -> next;
    head -> next = NULL;
}
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
list stone;

FILE* fp;

if (argc > 1)
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
else 
    fp = fopen("inp.txt", "r"); //CHANGED NAME OF FILE 

if (!fp)
    printf("Can't open file \n");
else {
    int value, state;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        state = fscanf(fp, "%d", &value);
        if (state != EOF){
            stone.insert(value);
        }

    } while (state != EOF);
     stone.showlist();
    fclose (fp);
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I made no formatting because I just wanted to see if the output works in first place. Now I found my mistakes and got it myself, too